# Access and Loop External Datasource with Apify Puppeteer Scraper

Tags: puppeteer, apify

The [Apify Puppeteer Scraper](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper) does not expose jquery in the [context object](https://apify.com/apify/puppeteer-scraper#context). I need to access an external JSON data source within the Puppeteer Scraper pageFunction and then loop over one of the nodes. Here is what I would do if jquery was available:

```
$.get(urlAPI, function(data) {
     $.each(data.feed.entry, function(index, value) {
        var url = value.URL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the handlePageFunction runs in node js context, there is no jQuery. You can easily include jQuery into page.evaluate function using Apify SDK.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { page, request, log, Apify } = context;
    await Apify.utils.puppeteer.injectJQuery(page);
    const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // There is jQuery include as we incleded it using injectJQuery method
        return $('title').text()
    });
    return {
        title,
    }
}
```

EDIT: Using [requestAsBrowser](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/utils#utilsrequestasbrowser-promise-httpincomingmessage-streamreadable).

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { page, request, log, Apify } = context;
    const response = await Apify.utils.requestAsBrowser({ url: "http://example.com" });
    const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
    return {
        data,
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to access external data source, web service, from the pageFuntion not the page.evaluate. will $.get work?

Comment: You cannot fetch data just using jQuery in evaluate method because you are in browser context there.
There is one more way you can use Apify.utils.requestAsBrowser({ url: "" }). It is not a standart way but it should work.

Comment: Apify.utils.requestAsBrowse just might work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery (you can if you are familiar with it) to access an external resource.

Usually, we extract external data via common libraries like [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or Apify's own [httpRequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apify/http-request) from a standalone actor. Unfortunately, Puppeteer Scraper doesn't allow usage of libraries (only dynamically downloaded which is probably overkill).

I would just use a modern [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) browser call. It is nicer than JQuery's AJAX and doesn't require inject.

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { page, request, log, Apify } = context;
    const json = await page.evaluate(() => {
        // There is jQuery include as we incleded it using injectJQuery method
        return await fetch('http://my-json-url.com').then((resp) => resp.json())
    });
    // Process the JSON
}
```